# NAvigationController Bar Buttons not showing

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have NavigationViewController class and in `viewDidload` methods 
like this. but Bar Buttons not showing any clue?

```
MapViewController *p=[[MapViewController alloc]initWithNibName:self.nibName bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"Code"
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(showDocco:)];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

    self.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self pushViewController:p animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yiğit, if you want to show the bar button items in `MapViewController` then your code should be like as follows.

```
     p.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
```

Lets say. you are in `HomeViewContrller` and you want to push `MapViewController` on button press. 
Your code is setting your bar button item in your `HomeViewController` becuase you set there `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;` in `viewDidLoad` method inside HomeViewController. it will access the navigation item of `HomeViewController`.

In short, each and every viewcontroller has its own navigation items. Either you should specify the barbutton item with particular viewcontroller reference as i showed you in my answer Or you can transfer your barbutton item code inside `MapViewController` `viewDidLoad` method.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you have given nib name and do you have navigation controller in the nib?If you dont have navigation bar then add one toolbar and add the bar button item to navigaiton bar.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: actually modalviewcontrollers will not come with navigation bar.you have to add toolbar in place of navigation bar and add barbutton item.and the functionality of bar button item is same just dismiss modal view or presented modal view..